# Starting Application On Specific Node in Hadoop Cluster

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig, hadoop2, cloudera-cdh

First of all, I'm using Hadoop-2.6.0. I want to launch app master on a specific set of node's in a YARN cluster as some of the nodes in my cluster are amazon spot machines and can be lost at any time. Is there a way in which i can launch an application master only on a particular set of machines ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes Definitely, you can start you AM on a specific node!

[ApplicationSubmissionContext](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/api/records/ApplicationSubmissionContext.html#setAMContainerResourceRequest(org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.ResourceRequest)) provides a function [setAMContainerResourceRequest](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/api/records/ApplicationSubmissionContext.html#setAMContainerResourceRequest%28org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.ResourceRequest%29) where you can pass a [ResourceRequest](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/api/records/ResourceRequest.html) object of your AM, In ResourceRequest object you can set "false" the RelaxLocality flag,  which tells the ResourceManager if the application wants locality to be loose (i.e. allows fall-through to rack or any) or strict (i.e. specify hard constraint on resource allocation). Then set the hostname using [setResourceName](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/api/records/ResourceRequest.html#setResourceName%28java.lang.String%29).

Further, If you need help to request an AM, please refer to the [Distributed Shell Example](https://github.com/apache/hadoop-common/tree/trunk/hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications/hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/applications/distributedshell)
I hope it helps!